# Problem in set position with Stack and Positioned in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a card with "balloon" in top of card [Here a example of what i'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBZ5Z.jpg)

I'm doin'g in Flutter, the last update, i've tried add stack with positioned, but i got this horrible [thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG6yD.jpg)

My code about this is:

```
Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text('1'),
              decoration:
              BoxDecoration(color: Colors.redAccent, shape: BoxShape.circle),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 19,
              top: 37,
              child: Container(
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Card(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Text('aaaaaaaa'),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

And my expected response was the link above

Comment: If you wanna get timeline like module then you should use timeline library from pub dart. furthermore, if my answer is not ok then you have to create by your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this :-

```
Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text('1'),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.redAccent, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 40,
                      width: 2,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Card(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text('aaaaaaaa'),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

[image]